# WMI causing memory leak(when run in multiple threads)

Tags: c#, thread-safety, wmi

My question is similar to [Periodical WMI Query Causes Memory Leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934639/periodical-wmi-query-causes-memory-leak) but with threads.

I am writing a simple application to monitor process and memory information from a number of servers.  However there is a memory leak.  I have whittled down the problem to the following simple Console application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;
using System.Threading;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void dummyQuery(string ip, string query)
        {
            ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
            ManagementScope mgtScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + ip + @"\ROOT\CIMV2", connOptions);


            mgtScope.Connect();

            ObjectQuery queryo = new ObjectQuery(query);

            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(mgtScope, queryo))
            {

                using (ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get())
                {

                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
            int times = 10000;
            for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
            {

                Thread t = new Thread(o => dummyQuery("xxxxxxxxx", @"SELECT WorkingSetSize FROM Win32_Process WHERE name='W3WP.exe'"));
                //t.IsBackground = true;

                t.Start();

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            //GC.Collect();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to run WMI queries from threads safely?

This is extracted from a much more complicated wpf application that checks the status of many servers much like the dummyQuery method.  That application leaks memory at a disturbingly fast rate related to WMI calls.  This sample looks like it is not leaking memory (Jim Mischel had a better way of checking this).  I will install a profiler and take another look at the original app.

Comment: Why are you calling GC.Collect(); manually?

Comment: Did you verify that there is a memory leak with memory profiler ?

Comment: also have you tried using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.wqlobjectquery.aspx

Comment: Stable when I try it.  Admittedly I didn't wait for 500000 msec.

Comment: I don't see how you can say that this is a memory leak. First, if memory usage is significantly less after the call to `GC.Collect`, that just indicates that the GC didn't see a need to collect before you called it. If memory usage doesn't change, that could just mean that the GC "freed" the memory, but kept it allocated/reserved as far as the OS is concerned. `GC.GetTotalMemory(true)` would give a better idea of how much memory is actually being used, but even that's insufficient. Without a memory profiler, all you have are wild guesses and uninformed speculation.

Comment: If you assert that there is a memory leak, please tell us how you diagnosed this leak, which memory profiling tool you used, and what the results were. I hope you weren't using Task Manager as your profiling tool.

Comment: I am now using WqlObjectQuery with no better results on the original application. It looks like the sample code isn't leaking.  I will look at the original app's code with a profile as soon as I get a chance.  Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Know that this is might be considered a dead thread but it was top of the search list when I was looking for a solution to the ManagementObjectSearcher memory leak issue that I was having.

My application is a multithreaded application that was calling WMI on the main thread as part of the initialisation process.  The application then spawned multiple thread non of which used WMI.  However, the application kept leaking memory when run as a Windows service (it was OK if it was run as a standard executable).

Putting [MTAThread] attribute on the Main entrypoint resolved the problem.

Comment: I can't actually confirm this is correct.  But I assume it is.